# Ampscript to detect if email in another another data extension in exact target

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm using exact target to send out an email.   I have two data extensions in exact target called `DEAllMembers` and `DESpecialMembers`.  Both data extensions have a field called `email_address`.

When crafting my email, I have a paragraph of text that I want show ONLY if the user's email address is in BOTH `DEAllMembers` and `DESpecialMembers`.  **I would like to use AMPScript to satisfy this objective.  Is this possible?  If so, how do I go about doing it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely possible.  You would use a conditional statement as described [in the documentation](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/)

```
%%[IF expression1 <comparison operator> expression2 THEN]%%
    [wrapped script or email content]
%%[ELSEIF expression1 <comparison operator> expression3 THEN]%%
    [wrapped script or email content]
%%[ELSE]%%
    [wrapped script or email content]
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

In your particular case you will also need a [DataExtension AMPScript function](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions) as well.

```
Lookup("DEAllMembers","email_address","email_address", emailaddr)
Lookup("DESpecialMembers","email_address","email_address", emailaddr)
```

Your final AMP script would look something like this -

```
%%[
    SET @all    Lookup("DEAllMembers","email_address","email_address", emailaddr)
    SET @special    Lookup("DESpecialMembers","email_address","email_address", emailaddr)

    IF EMPTY(@all) AND EMPTY(@special) THEN
]%%

<p>Your content here</p>

%%[ENDIF]%%
```